# Windows Phone Application bar icons issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm developing an application on windows phone 8. The problem is the app bar icons are not showing and instead of the actual icon it just showing a cross. The funny thing is on the design page it's ok but when I run the app they are just a cross.

I've set the properties to **content and don't copy** but it still not working.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
     <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Mode="Default" >
         <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Add"    
                  IconUri="/projectname;component/Assets/DefualtIcons/add.png"/>
         <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Help" 
                  IconUri="/projectname;component/Assets/DefualtIcons/help.png"/>
         <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Settings"/>
         </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
     </shell:ApplicationBar>
 </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

**Solution**
For those who are having the same problem as me this is the resolution:

1. set the properties to Content and do not copy
2. put the images in a image folder. (for some reason the folder name must be image)
3. do not set the IconUri like any of these. even if you see the icon in the design.

   /ProjectName;component/Image/help.png

   ~/Image/help.png

   ../Image/help.png
4. the IconUri has to be like this:
   /Image/help.png

Comment: *don't copy*? Are you sure that's what you meant?

Comment: is the IconUri path correct?

Comment: the properties I set it to Do not copy and Content.

Comment: yes the path is correct. it is showing in the design page.

Comment: change IconUri="/projectname;component/Assets/DefualtIcons/add.png"/ to IconUri="/Assets/DefualtIcons/add.png" and see.

Comment: I have tried all sort of uris but none of them working.

Comment: Don't know, But there is something wrong in the path fore sure. Otherwise, all the things are set perfectly. Please check for the path and the folder hierarchy properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the properties of add.png and help.png to content. You did every thing right but you make mistake to set IconUri ="/projectname;component/Assets/DefualtIcons/add.png"., the way set IconUri you was used. useful only when you set Images properties to Resources.
Here is the sample code, this may help you.

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
         <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Mode="Default" >
             <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Add"    
                      IconUri="/Assets/DefualtIcons/add.png"/>
             <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Help" 
                      IconUri="/Assets/DefualtIcons/help.png"/>
             <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Settings"/>
             </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
         </shell:ApplicationBar>
     </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Assuming u have copied your icons to images folder in your project.Change the properties of images to **Content** and **CopyAlways**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
     <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Mode="Default" >
         <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Add"    
                  IconUri="/Images/DefualtIcons/add.png"/>
         <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Help" 
                  IconUri="/Images/DefualtIcons/help.png"/>
         <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Settings"/>
         </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
     </shell:ApplicationBar>
 </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Comment: it's just the folder name on the properties page.

Comment: @Daniel i meant properties of IMAGES should be Content and CopyAlways

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and i solve it by Adding a new Folder Image in my project and copy these images on this folder

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
     <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Mode="Default" >
         <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Add"    
                  IconUri="..Image /add.png"/>
         <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Help" 
                  IconUri="..Image/help.png"/>
         <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Settings"/>
         </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
     </shell:ApplicationBar>
 </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Comment: that's odd.. but let me try that.

Comment: plz check what is the size of add.png and help.png

Comment: I've just got it from Mincrosoft SDKs folder in Program file and didn't change the size. what size it must be?

Comment: changing the size didn't work. I've changed the size to 24*24 but still nothing.